# show div onchange of dropdownlist value using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist and I want to show a **div** `onchange` event using javascript but it says **object required**

aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lstFilePrefix1" onchange="showTR();" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Prefix1" Value="Prefix1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Prefix2" Value="Prefix2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Prefix3" Value="Prefix3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Prefix1 and Prefix2" Value="Prefix1 and Prefix2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Prefix2 and Prefix3" Value="Prefix2 and Prefix3" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and javascript code inside .js file

```
function showTR() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "<%=lstFilePrefix1.ClientID%>" ); // Get a reference to the dropdown (select) element
    var selectedItemValue = dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value; // use the dropdown reference to get the selected item's value
    var div2 = document.getElementById( "data" ); // Get a reference to div2

    if( selectedItemValue == 'Prefix2' ) {
        div2.style.dispaly= "block";// If the selectedItemValue is 'Action', show div2
    } else {
        div2.style.display = "none"; // Otherwise, hide div2
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code is cut and paste there is a typo: div2.style.dispaly should be div2.style.display ... Kindness, Dan

Answer (score 0):

Well I might be mistaken but JavaScript doesn't accept asp code. Unless of course you are outputting inside.js as asp with the correct header. Also you have a typeo at `div2.style.dispaly`

```
function showTR() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "#anID" ); // Get a reference to the dropdown (select) element
    var selectedItemValue = dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value; // use the dropdown reference to get the selected item's value
    var div2 = document.getElementById( "data" ); // Get a reference to div2

    if( selectedItemValue == 'Prefix2' ) {
        div2.style.display = "block";// If the selectedItemValue is 'Action', show div2
    } else {
        div2.style.display = "none"; // Otherwise, hide div2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
div2.style.visibility = "visible";
```

or

```
div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: This answer is too short and doesn't meet SO quality standards. Please, improve it adding some explanations so that it will be useful for the community and not only for the OP.